# How to add auto taxonomy to node fields?

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

How to add auto categorization(Taxonomy Term) to node based on node body/description.

Node Body/Description: **Retro is back in style, so flaunt the same when wearing this T-shirt from PUMA. Fashioned for men, this piece can be easily worn when heading out for a crazy day ahead with friends. Live in the moment by wearing this T-shirt with casual trousers and flip-flops when you hit the street with your best buddies**
Here i have : ->T-Shirts, flip-flops, MEN etc,
By reading this content i want to assign auto **taxonomy term reference in node field** as T-Shirts to node.
Is it possible to do this?
Anyone help me ASAP.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, there is a few modules which can handle it:

1. [Word Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/word_link) (I recommend it)

> The Word Link module allows you to automatically convert specific
>   words into links. It works as text filter. This can be useful for
>   crossposting your site's pages, or for the contextual advertising of
>   your partners (SEO).

2. [Active Taxonomy Links](https://www.drupal.org/project/active_taxonomy_links)

> Active Taxonomy Links module processes nodes of selected content types
>   replacing words in the nodes with links to taxonomy terms.

3. [Glossify](https://www.drupal.org/project/glossify) (this one supports Drupal 6 also)

> The Glossify module provides filters that scan and parse content and
>   replace terms in the text with links to their pages. The d7 version is
>   a complete rewrite of the module to be as simple and performant as
>   possible.